# Selecting first alphabet in a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

Example -

"Let this be the test sentence" , Suppose this line is selected , I need a Word macro to select only the first alphabet , that is 'L' and then format it in which ever way I want...
I am unable to get the macro to select only the first alphabet from the selected line.
I have tried this -
`'Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine

Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

Selection.Expand wdLine

MsgBox (Selection.Text)`

Can somebody please give me an answer to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the first character in the selection?

```
MsgBox Selection.Characters(1)
```

Or, to use it to make that character bold:

```
Dim firstChar As Word.Range
Set firstChar = Selection.Characters(1)
firstChar.Bold = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim firstAlphabet As Range

    Selection.SetRange Start:=0, End:=1 '<--| collapse Selection to its first character

    Set firstAlphabet = Selection.Range
    ' now use 'firstAlphabet ' range for your formatting


End Sub
```